# How to combine string elements of a list for Apriori Algorithm in python?

Tags: python, apriori, lis

So I am trying to program Apriori Algorithm.
I have here

```
L1= ['apple', 'banana','orange','mango]
```

This list already passed the support threshold, now I have to combine the items for another support threshold which should look like this:

```
C2 = [['apple','banana'],['apple','orange'],['apple','mango']]
```

Comment: Are you just looking for something like `l = L1.pop(0)` and `C2 = [[l, val] for val in L1]`? Or something more specific?

Comment: No. I'm looking for an answer to combine each element like C2 = [['apple','banana'],['apple','orange'],['apple','mango']] then C3 will be [[banana, orange],[banana,mango]]

Comment: My example creates C2 exactly like that...

Answer (score 1):

```
L1= ['apple', 'banana','orange','mango']
C2 = [[L1[0], i] for i in L1[1:]]
```

Result `C2`:

```
[['apple', 'banana'], ['apple', 'orange'], ['apple', 'mango']]
```

To run this for all items in the list:

```
C2 = []
for i in L1:
    l = [[i, x] for x in L1 if not i == x]
    C2.extend(l)
```

Comment: thank you! but what should i do if i will combine the next elements with other elements like [['banana','orange'],['banana','mango']]? Note that it skips ['banana', 'apple'] since it's the same with ['apple', 'banana']

Comment: You should use list.pop(0) to create the lists in a loop for i in range(len(L1)), that way you won't have duplicates.

Comment: it returned an empty list when i used the pop

Comment: @MessyMaze in that case we'd have to include another for loop, I have updated the answer. Don't use `pop` because it removes items from L1.